# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT at TypeORM postgresql connexion on public Wifi

Tags: tcp, nestjs, typeorm

My NESTjs server can not initialize TypeOrmModule on local if I use a public Wifi. But it works well in production, staging and local (using smartphone connexion).

Here is what I have at start :

```
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +56ms
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [InstanceLoader] MailerModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [InstanceLoader] MailerCoreModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [InstanceLoader] MailjetModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:38:09   [InstanceLoader] MailModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 8348   - 13/01/2022, 13:39:25   [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +75358ms
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.74.156.137:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1146:16)
```

Comment: do you use some security group for your database server? I guess you was not allowed to connect to db because your IP is not in "white" list when you're using public Wi-Fi

Comment: The postgres database is hosted by heroku (I may forget this important detail)